# Debezium Server for Azure Event hub sink send messages to multiple partition keys

Tags: postgresql, azure-eventhub, debezium, change-data-capture

I'm implementing CDC for a PostgreSQL azure database.  And I want the events to be sent to azure event hub.  My current plan is to use Debezium Server with the Event Hub sink to do this. However I want to enforce order of events by table.  From [this article](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428) I know I can do this by having a single topic with multiple partitions but only sending events from a single table to a specific partition every time.

However it seems like debezium doesn't provide a nice way to handle this. You can specify the partition key for all events to be sent to, but not dynamically per event.  The only other thing I saw that could solve this is a custom sink implementation or a custom EventHubProducerClient implementation passed into the config.

What are my options for handling this? Is there another way to architect this solution so that I don't have to use partition keys?  Or is a custom sink implementation going to be my best bet? Or should i just drop debezium and write a custom listener/publisher?

Context / requirements

- typically to run debezium you need a kafka instance running, however
  if possible I don't want to use kafka as I'm already planning on
  using event hub, and it seems duplicitous, and it is another service that needs to be maintained.
- FIFO ordering of events by table when read by consumers of the event hub
- all logical database changes are turned into events
- no java developers on the team so the custom (java) implementations will be a stretch to our expertise.

Comment: did you finish the solution and can you please share your experience, I am also try to acheive same thing

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I need to do the same as well. Please share if you found one. thanks

Comment: @Dark_Knight unfortunately i haven't gotten an answer to this yet

Comment: @Zooloo10, A workaround to this (which I think it is not efficient); create multiple Debezium servers each one is configured to listen on specific table(s) (different than others) and then add different partition key for each Debezium Server.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to the Event Hubs sink, but would explore partition routing to see if this could solve the issue: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/transformations/partition-routing.html

Comment: Are you sure you need ordering for the whole table? Usually it's enough that ordering is ensured per entity/table row. If that is enough, then partitionKey is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example configuration:

```
debezium.source.table.include.list=dbo.TableOne,dbo.TableTwo,dbo.TableThree
debezium.source.transforms=PartitionRouting
debezium.source.transforms.PartitionRouting.type=io.debezium.transforms.partitions.PartitionRouting
debezium.source.transforms.PartitionRouting.partition.payload.fields=source.table,source.table,source.table
debezium.source.transforms.PartitionRouting.partition.topic.num=32
```

The `partition.payload.fields` setting ([see docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/transformations/partition-routing.html#partition-routing-configuration-options)) determines which field in the event should be used by the hash function that distributes events across partitions. `source.table` will be the table name without the schema, so `TableOne`/`TableTwo`/`TableThree` in this example.

Given the above configuration, all events from `TableOne`/`TableTwo`/`TableThree` will be sent to exactly one partition (probably to three different ones, one per table). So only 3 of the configured 32 partitions would be used.

If the setting was
`fields=source.table,source.table,change.Id` then all events from `TableOne` and `TableTwo` would be sent to their own partitions, while the events from `TableThree` would be evenly divided between all the 32 partitions (but all events for a particular row would always be sent to the same partition).